# Unit Testing Links With Only Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-router-dom

I was wondering if there was a way to unit test links with jest alone to make sure they go to the correct place. All other resources I have looked up have used enzyme or additional applications.

For example:
Ensuring `<Link to '/homepage>` or `<NavLink to '/homepage'>` actually goes to the homepage.

Any additional resources to read would also be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the `Link` component with jestjs, `react-dom`, and `history` packages. We spy on the `history.push()` method before user click the `Link`, the `Link` component will call `history.push()` underly when user click it.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export function About() {
  return <Link to="/home">home</Link>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act, Simulate } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { About } from './';

describe('70535778', () => {
  let container: HTMLDivElement | null = null;
  let memoryHistory, pushSpy, replaceSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    memoryHistory = createMemoryHistory();
    pushSpy = jest.spyOn(memoryHistory, 'push');
    replaceSpy = jest.spyOn(memoryHistory, 'push');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    unmountComponentAtNode(container!);
    container!.remove();
    container = null;
    pushSpy.mockRestore();
    replaceSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  test('should pass', () => {
    act(() => {
      render(
        <Router history={memoryHistory}>
          <About />
        </Router>,
        container
      );
    });
    const a = container!.querySelector('a')!;
    Simulate.click(a, { defaultPrevented: false, button: 0 });
    expect(pushSpy).toBeCalledWith('/home');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70535778/index.test.tsx (12.11 s)
  70535778
    ✓ should pass (31 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.443 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Comment: I am receiving an error that says `Non-null assertions can only be used in TypeScript files.`

Comment: @ARay17 violates this rule https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-non-null-assertion.md? Just disable it

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding everything. I keep getting errors that certain code only applies to typescript.